# How to delete child object in Strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

I used this topic to delete upload related to articles and it work :
[How to delete file from upload folder in strapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551844/how-to-delete-file-from-upload-folder-in-strapi/63605538#63605538)

Now i want a cascade deletion. For when i delete a project, articles and upload will deleted also.
Somebody know how to delete a project which will delete an article & upload file ?

This code work to delete a project and children but not the file. And if i try to delete just an article, the controller is called and the file is deleted.

/api/projects/controllers/projects.js

```
module.exports = {
  async delete(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;

    const project = await strapi.services.projects.delete({ id });

    if (project){
      for (let article of project.articles) {
        strapi.services.articles.delete({ 'id' : article._id } );
      }
    }

    return sanitizeEntity(project, { model: strapi.models.projects });
  }
```

/api/articles/services/articles.js

```
delete(params) {
    return strapi.query('articles').delete(params);
}
```

/api/articles/controllers/article.js

```
module.exports = {
  async delete(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
        
    const entity = await strapi.services.articles.delete({ id });
        
      if (entity) {
          strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.remove(entity.articleFile);
      }
      
      return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.articles });
  }
}
```

The controller is called when i used the url in API like that :
DELETE http://localhost:port/banners/<project_ID>

The strapi.services.xxx.delete is called in the code

Answer (score 0):

Actually you remove articles files only when you pass into your article controller. But in project controller context, you never remove files.

To fix it, remove article files into the article service.

/api/articles/services/articles.js

```
async delete(params) {
    const entity = await strapi.query('articles').delete(params);
    
    if (entity) {
      await strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.remove(entity.articleFile);
    }

    return entity; 
}
```

/api/articles/controllers/article.js

module.exports = {

```
  async delete(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
        
    const entity = await strapi.services.articles.delete({ id });
    // here articles files have been deleted by services.articles.delete    
  
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.articles });
  }
}
```

According to strapi concepts :

> **Services** are a set of **reusable functions**. They are particularly useful to respect the DRY (don’t repeat yourself) programming concept and to simplify controllers logic.

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/services.html#concept

> **Controllers** are JavaScript files which contain a set of methods called actions reached by the client **according to the requested route**. It means that every time a client requests the route, the action performs the business logic coded and sends back the response. They represent the C in the MVC pattern. In most cases, the controllers will contain the bulk of a project's business logic.

[https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/controllers.htm](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/controllers.html#concept)

Comment: Great it work, but i had to add async await on /api/articles/services/articles.js

Else, i had this message :
(node:22972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: Thanks for feedback, i have edited my answer to add async/await